# php array within function only 1 result

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I can not figure out how to get $output working within this function.

```
    <?php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
function fill_unit_select_box($conn)
    { 
     $output = '';
     $query = "SELECT * from `skater` ORDER By `skater`.`skater_name_first` ASC";
     $result = $conn->query($query);
    
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["skater_NUM"].'">'.$row["skater_NUM"].''.$row["skater_NUM"].'</option>';
      //$output .= '<option value="'.$row["skater_NUM"].'">'.$row["skater_name_first"].''.$row["skater_name_last"].'</option>';
 }
 return $output;
}

?>
```

Function is called later.

```
<option value="">Select Unit</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($conn); ?></select>
```

If I use the following nothing works.  The option fields are not displayed in the select.

```
output .= '<option value="'.$row["skater_NUM"].'">'.$row["skater_name_last"].''.$row["skater_name_first"].'</option>';
```

If I use the following the function works.

```
output .= '<option value="'.$row["skater_NUM"].'">'.$row["skater_NUM"].''.$row["skater_NUM"].'</option>';
```

Calling anything except skater_NUM causes issues.

If I call the function outside of the following the function works.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_quantity[]" class="form-control item_quantity" /></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="">Select Unit</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($conn); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
  $('#item_table').append(html);
 });
```

The function is working.  Just the add row .add button will not add new rows with anything other then numbers for skater_NUM field.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_quantity[]" class="form-control item_quantity" /></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="">Select Unit</option><option value="8">Skater1</option><option value="21">Skater2</option></select></td>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
  $('#item_table').append(html);
 });
```

Comment: `$output .=` would concatenate the result into the existing string each time you loop, so you get more than one option, not sure why you commented that out?

Comment: I find if I call anything except $row["skater_NUM"] I get errors.  I might have to rephrase my question.

Comment: If you get errors, obviously you need to tell us what they are. [edit] your post to clarify what the real problem is.

Comment: What does `skater` have in it? Are the "issues" warnings or something else? Please describe the issue with more details.

Comment: As per [ask], please include all code and data as text, not pictures. And "issues" isn't an error message or a useful problem description - as I requested before, if you get an error, tell us what it is. We cannot necessarily guess.

Comment: Can you _please_ define what exactly you mean by "issues"...what goes wrong when you use those other fields? Do you get an error message , or other unexpected output? (it may be buried in your HTML source, you may have to use View Source in your browser to see it - unless you've got PHP error logging enabled maybe.)

Comment: Make sure you've got mysqli error reporting enabled, too: add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a PHP problem, a MySQL problem, or an HTML problem?

Comment: I am discovering as I go.  Thank you everyone for your help so far.  I believe this is a javascript problem.

Comment: What makes you say that, then? Give us more details.  What happens when you run the add when any other values are present except the num?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable $output is replaced in every loop, $output will give you the result of the last row.
Solution try to replace $output by
`$output .=`

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out...  add ".."  Now the echo likes characters other then numbers....  This took was too long.

```
html += '<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="">Select Unit</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($conn); ?></select></td>';
```

to

```
html += '<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="">Select Unit</option>"<?php echo fill_unit_select_box($conn); ?>"</select></td>';
```

Comment: Cam you share more details? Whats the difference between the first and the second snippet?

Comment: Add "" to php echo"<?php echo fill_unit_select_box($conn); ?>"

Comment: What do you mean by that? Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Comment: There appears to be no difference between these two pieces of code

Comment: he added quotes where it makes no sense, around a couple of option tags